# Flutter app not running (Error output cocoapods)

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

When I run in an iphone simulator this happens, but if I remove the dependencies everything runs normal

I already did the following process

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run

Output

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           2,905ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `camera` from `.symlinks/plugins/camera/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `camerawesome` from `.symlinks/plugins/camerawesome/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_image_compress` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_image_compress/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `geolocator` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `native_device_orientation` from `.symlinks/plugins/native_device_orientation/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `permission_handler` from `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `video_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
```

The packages i'm using

- cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
- shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
- url_launcher: ^5.7.10
- liquid_swipe: ^1.5.0
- geolocator: ^6.1.9
- flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0
- permission_handler: ^4.4.0+hotfix.4
- change_app_package_name: ^0.1.2
- fluttertoast: ^7.1.8
- camera: ^0.7.0+2
- video_player: ^1.0.1
- camerawesome: ^0.2.2
- native_device_orientation: ^0.4.3
- flutter_speed_dial: ^1.0.9
- path_provider:
- dropdown_search:
- path:
- flutter_svg: